# How can i use sub process in APS/activiti

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn, alfresco-enterprise

Requirement :

1. Candidates will Fill Application Form.
2. HR will review the application and submits for Technical Team Approval(P2).
3. After Technical team review HR need not to wait for Manger approval and HR should be able to get technical team data(with or without manager approval).
4. HR should be able to submit for Final Approval.

P1:
[image: process one]

P2:
[image: process two]

Solutions I have tried:

1. If i use Collapsed sub process i need to wait till the completion of Manager Approval task.
2. I tried using the sub process, throwing and catching events. Created two sub process, 1st sub process will throw signal and second sub process will catch signal if HR submits another application the 2nd sub process will not catch the signal.
3. If i use Call Activity multi-instance type as Sequential i need to provide Cardinality it will be fixed number of application HR will be able to submit for Technical Approval, in my case it should not be fixed number of loop.
4. If i use Call Activity, the Call Activity will not share its data to P1 process, in my case data should be shared from P2 to P1.

Kindly any one help me.

Thanks & Regards
Amruta Wandakar

Comment: so the manager approval is `optional` if HR approves. but what if manager approves? will it go for a final approval? or to the HR?

Comment: @AbbasKararawala The data of the manager approval should be visible to HR or at the Final Approval.